# How does the 'prototype' object have access to the newly created object for 'this'?

Tags: javascript

```
var Person = function() {
    this.name = "Jay";
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
}

var jay = new Person();
console.log(jay.getName()); // Jay
console.log(Person.prototype); // { getName: [Function] }
```

When I call `new Person()` I think it sets `jay's` internal `[[prototype]]` property as `Person.prototype` object. So I understand that when I try to access a property that doesn't exist like `getName` it will check the object's `[[prototype]]` which is `Person.prototype` for getName. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

What I'm confused about is how the `Person.prototype` object is able to access `jay` from `this`? From what I understand `this` refers to the object invoking the method, which is `Person.prototype` not `jay`, and this object doesn't hold `name` property.

Comment: The following answer may be helpful in figuring out more about prototype, constructor functions and the value of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing "the place where the method is defined" with "the object performing the method." It is *defined* on Person.prototype, but the method is invoked on that particular object.

Comment: Just to confirm, when the prototype chain finds `getName` will it do `jay.getName = Person.prototype.getName` before performing the method?  Or use `call` method? Thanks

Comment: @Jay: Neither, really. The prototype chain is used to look up the property in the first place, so there is no need to copy anything, and `call()` isn't necessary — but the effect is much the same as if you'd used `call` with the function.